# How to setup gitblit with gerrit on windows?

Tags: git, gerrit, gitblit

[**Update in 2013.12.17**]

According to the comments below, I upgrade gerrit to 2.8 and gitblit to 1.3.2, same as before.

Compiling gitblit from source is complex, I extract the jar from gitblit.zip from [github release](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/releases)

[**Update end**]

I try to install gerrit (2.8) with gitblit (1.3.2) plugins on windows for demo, gerrit works and gitblit plugin is installed with links available, while when it states "Not found" when I browse branch.

Below are my steps on Windows using MSysGit environment

```
$ java -jar gerrit-2.8.war init -d review 
# use ldap to connect local ldap server, others are default
# copy gitblit plugin into plugins' folder
$ unzip gitblit-1.3.2.zip
$ cp gitblit.jar review/plugins/gitblit.jar
```

Update the `etc/gerrit.config` for gitblit

```
[gitweb]
type = custom
url  = plugins/
project = gitblit/summary/${project}
revision = gitblit/commit/${project}/${commit}
branch = gitblit/log/${project}/${branch}
filehistory = gitblit/history/${project}/${branch}/${file}
linkname = GitBlit
```

Now start the gerrit

```
$ java -jar review/bin/gerrit.war daemon -d review
```

The gerrit is started as normal, and the gitblit link is available for the branches, see [image: snapshot]

While when I click the gitblit link, it is stated below (url link is http:///plugins/gitblit/log/gtr/HEAD , can't find any error in `logs` directory

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /plugins/gitblit/log/gtr/HEAD. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have tried to install GitBlit itself instead of the plugin. This does not work. In order to be able to use GitBlit as a plugin in Gerrit, you have to compile it yourself.

Download source code from [GitBlit-Plugin-Source](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/gitblit/). The resulting artifact (gitblit-plugin-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar, use the stable-2.8 branch) can be copied into the Gerrit plugin folder.

*However*:

The current GitBlit Plugin does **not** work with Gerrit 2.7. You either need 2.5 or 2.8.

Comment: I switched to gerrit2.8, but the gitblit integration can't be automatically detected as well.

Comment: @LarryCai Did you: Download the **source** from the URL above, build it and put the result from the build (gitblit-plugin-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar, **not** gitblit.jar) into your plugin directory? I should show up automatically. Don't use your custom links just yet. Go to _Plugins -> installed_ and see if the plugin shows up.

Comment: too complicated for me to build jar from source by myself due to knowledge of maven and lots of dependance, can you send me the jar file for testing ? larry.caiyu (at) gmail.com , thanks

Comment: @LarryCai If you are in a no proxy environment, downloading and building takes about 4 min. Clone plugin repo, download and unzip maven (3.0.5 works) in a separate directory. CD into the plugin dir, type "<path-to-maven>/bin/mvn clean package". Afterwards, the compiled plugin is inside the target folder. If you have a proxy in your environment, you need to edit <path-to-maven>/conf/settings.xml (it is well documented).

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions in http://www.slideshare.net/lucamilanesio/gitblit-plugin-for-gerrit-code-review and quickly integrated gitblit into my gerrit 2.8 setup. (Well, I had to checkout the right branch of gitblit, I used 2.8-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: I can't find the information of "an automatic gerrit init-setup", when I do setup using command `java -jar gerrit-2.8.war init -d review`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds too complicated, I would recommend trying GitBlit. Take a look at [Setup git server on windows in few clicks](http://svnrating.com/setup-git-server-windows-clicks/) tutorial about how to get everything up and running in few minutes.

Comment: very useful link, thanks. But I need to install gerrit, which provides code review features.